# What is causing this build error targeting iphonesimulator from Visual Studio?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I'm getting these errors, building for any iOS simulator:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(473,3): error MSB3231: Unable to remove directory "obj\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\". The directory is not empty*

OR

*SeverityCodeDescriptionProjectFileLineSuppression StateSuppression State Error Unable to remove directory "UserControls". Access to the path 'D:\Projects\Solutions\mycompany\iOS\obj\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\UserControls' is denied.mycompany.iOS*

OR both together...

I'm using VS 2019 version 16.3.7 on Windows 10 machine and Xcode 11.2.1 on Mac Mini, OSX 10.14.6 and it does not matter which iOS simulator targeted, all version 13.2.2. Developing a Xamarin Forms application.

If I switch to target one of my hard devices, I get multiple errors like this:
*error : Access to the path 'D:\Projects\Solutions\mycompany\iOS\obj\iPhone\Debug\Popups\TemplatePicker.xaml.g.cs' is denied.*

I can work around this by quitting VS, removing read-only flag on the obj folder and all it contents, run VS as admin, THEN it builds and pushes to the device.

Switching back to target a simulator, I get the first error again.

Deleting Bin and Obj folders does not help either.

Side note - this was working until Windows rebooted itself on my dev machine, closing VS and forcing recovery of some files. Android version works just fine in simulator and hard device, no issues.

Wondering if I upgrade VS to version 16.4.5 and Xcode to 11.3.1, this might be resolved. Any ideas?
Are these version compatible with the latest VS-Xcode connector? (I've seen issues with version incompatibility) .

Any ideas? Resolutions?

Thank you

Comment: Does it work if you choose a short project name? Does it work if you create the project in a short directory such as `C:\code`?

Comment: OK, here's what I've found...
The connection and link to XCode from VS on the PC causes a lock or some sort when targeting any iOS simulor.
This is intermittent but once the locks are imposed, one needs to 
- close VS
- quit the Simulator on the Mac.
- delete the Obj and Bin folders in the solution
- Re-open VS, open the project, let it sync with the Mac.
- Restart Simulator on the mac
- Rebuild
This could take a couple iterations too.
If that does not clear the problem, shut down both machines, remember to delete Obj and Bin folders.
Frustrating, slow, but t works for me for now .

Comment: You can share your solution in the answer which can help more people with same problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's what I've found...

The connection and link to XCode from VS on the PC causes a lock or some sort when targeting any iOS simulor. This is intermittent but once the locks are imposed, one needs to

- close VS
- quit the Simulator on the Mac.
- delete the Obj and Bin folders in the solution
- Re-open VS, open the project, let it sync with the Mac.
- Restart Simulator on the mac
- Rebuild. This could take a couple iterations too.

If that does not clear the problem, shut down both machines, remember to delete Obj and Bin folders.

Frustrating, slow, but it works for me for now.